# Required field validation on microsoft excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2003, vba

I have 5 columns (SNO,Name,Phone,Address,Pin)  in excel(2003/2007).
Excel can have "n" no. of records.
I want to apply a validation , such that , when we save the excel sheet,value of "SNO"(which contains integer value) column should never be empty , when any one (Name,Phone,Address,Pin) column has value.
If this is not the case then an error message should come.
I am entering the data manually.
I tried :
EDIT:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("SNO").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must fill in SNO."
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Can we apply the validation , without writing the code?

Comment: @brettdj/brettdjI have edited my question , with the effort that I put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as I can tell VBA is the best (only?) way to do this.

Try

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim dat As Variant

    ' change to your sheet name
    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        ' Get data range to check
        ' Assumes SNO is column A and Name etc is Column B to E
        Set rng = .Range(.UsedRange.Columns(1), .UsedRange.Columns(5))
        For Each rw In rng.Rows
            ' If SNO cell is empty
            If rw.Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
                ' Check if other cells are not blank
                dat = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rw.Value)))
                If dat <> "" Then
                    MsgBox "You must fill in SNO."
                    Cancel = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```